# Is it possible in Android to add a custom view composed of standard views and use it in code but have the layout know only about the standard views?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have this pseudo-layout structure in a separate file representing the custom view:

```xml
<FrameLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <Button/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and this is my pseudo-layout for a fragment:

```xml
<ConstraintLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <MyCustomView/>
   <TextView/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to reuse `MyCustomView` in two places that need their own styling for the internal `TextView` and `Button`, but I don't know of a way to do it in a simple way. It would be much easier if I could expand `MyCustomView` in the fragment layout into:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <FrameLayout> <!--(or MyCustomView instead of FrameLayout, it would be a better indicator of what it is)-->
      <TextView style="fancy_background"/>
      <Button/>
   </FrameLayout>
   <TextView/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Is it actually possible in Android? If yes, then how to set it up?

Comment: You can expose various properties via public attributes for your custom view, so when your layout uses `<MyCustomView />` you could say: `<MyCustomView someAttr="xxx" />` for example. And it's up to your custom view to handle the value (and do whatever it means). You could (for e.g.) have an attribute called `titleBackgroundStyle` and you apply that style to your TextView at runtime when you inflate your view. You can also use the `<merge` to avoid introducing an extra "nesting layer" in your layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Custom Attributes.

Imagine you have a "Custom View" that takes a title and an image. You could add to your `attrs.xml` the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
        <attr name="title" format="string|reference" />
        <attr name="android:drawable" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

You'd then implement this custom view in Code:

(something like this... keep in mind this is "pseudo code", I took it from a custom view I have, but it's greatly simplified for the purposes of this...)
In this custom view, I can supply a title and an image, and will also use a custom background (not included in the demo) :)

```
class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    @AttrRes defStyle: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    private val title: MaterialTextView
    private val image: ImageView

    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.HERE_GOES_THE_LAYOUT, this).also {
            title = it.findViewById(R.id.title)
            image = it.findViewById(R.id.image
            // set some properties (just an example)
            it.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.EXAMPLE_OF_A_BACKGROUND)
            it.isClickable = true
            it.isFocusable = true

            // I want this view to be clickable and provide material feedback...
            val foregroundResId = context.theme.getThemeAttributeValue(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, false)
            it.foreground = context.theme.getDrawable(foregroundResId)
        }


        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomView, defStyle, 0).run {
            initProperties(this)
            recycle()
        }
    }

    private fun initProperties(typedArray: TypedArray) = with(typedArray) {
        // The names of these attrs are a mix from attr.xml + the attr name.
        getString(R.styleable.MyCustomView_title).also { setTitle(it) }
        getDrawable(R.styleable.MyCustomView_android_drawable).also { setImage(it) }
    }

    private fun setTitle(title: CharSequence?) {
        title.text = title
    }

    private fun setImage(source: Drawable?) {
        source?.let {
            image.setImageDrawable(it)
        }
    }
}
```

This is all supported by my layout: `R.layout.HERE_GOES_THE_LAYOUT`

Here's a simplified version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</merge>
```

#### And how do I use this?

In any layout! E.g.:

```
<Some ViewGroup like LinearLayout It Doesn't Matter .... >

   <com.the.package.of.your.MyCustomView
      android:id="@+id/yourCustomViewOne"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   <!-- HERE ARE THE TWO 'custom' ATTRIBUTES -->
      android:drawable="@drawable/some_drawable_of_your_choice"
      app:title="@string/some_string" />

   <com.the.package.of.your.MyCustomView
      android:id="@+id/yourCustomViewTwo"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:drawable="@drawable/a_different_drawable_perhaps"
      app:title="@string/and_also_a_different_string />

</Some ViewGroup like LinearLayout It Doesn't Matter>
```

Hopefully you get the idea. You can add more custom attributes, or even (like I did) use an Android one, and internally give it your own meaning (overriding an android attribute and misusing it would likely confuse your users, so be "smart"). E.g.: if the above custom view had MORE than one image, using `android:Drawable` may not be a great choice, because users wouldn't be sure what drawable is that thing setting... in this example it works "fine" because you only have one image.

Last but not least, don't neglect Accessibility! Provide descriptions where you see fit, test with TalkBack, etc.

#### How does this answer the question?

Well, you don't need to "expand" the custom view, you just need to *encapsulate* the dynamic properties so whoever is using the Widget/View, can provide the values via XML (or programmatically) and your custom view *does the job* behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using include + databinding

Step 1. Create a layout for your custom view like below.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="myText"
        type="java.lang.String" />

</data>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{myText}" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Step 2. Include it in your Fragment/Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/MyCustomView"
            layout="@layout/my_custom_view"
            app:myText="@{`aaa`}"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

> You might need to use binding adapter to pass **style** as an attribute